# node-gyp ignores (c++17) cflag

Tags: node.js, c++17, node-gyp, node.js-addon

I try to configure & build a node.js C++ addon with this 
binding.gyp file:

```
{ 
  "targets": [
    {
      "target_name": "addon",
      "sources": [ "addon.cpp" ],
      "cflags": [
        "-std=c++17"
      ]          
    }
  ]
}
```

But when I run `node-gyp configure` and `node-gype rebuild`
I always get messages like

> warning: ‘if constexpr’ only available with -std=c++17 or -std=gnu++17

The build also fails, because I really depend on these c++17 features. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using **`"cflags_cc"`** (instead of `"cflags"`) works.

This solved the problem.

Answer (score 6):

cflags  cflags_cc was not working for me, but with the setting in VCCLCompilerTool it works (on Windows):

```
{
  'targets': [
    {
      'target_name': 'test-napi-native',
      'sources': [ 'src/test_napi.cc' ],
      'include_dirs': ["<!@(node -p \"require('node-addon-api').include\")"],
      'dependencies': ["<!(node -p \"require('node-addon-api').gyp\")"],
      'cflags': [ '-fno-exceptions' ],
      'cflags_cc': [ '-fno-exceptions' ],
      'xcode_settings': {
        'GCC_ENABLE_CPP_EXCEPTIONS': 'YES',
        'CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY': 'libc++',
        'MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET': '10.7'
      },
      'msvs_settings': {
        'VCCLCompilerTool': { "ExceptionHandling": 1, 'AdditionalOptions': [ '-std:c++17' ] }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## The default is against your will

[`node-gyp` has default settings.](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/blob/a26494fbb8883d9ef784503979e115dec3e2791e/lib/configure.js#L274-L295)

```
argv.push('-I', addonGypi)
argv.push('-I', commonGypi)
argv.push('-Dlibrary=shared_library')
argv.push('-Dvisibility=default')
argv.push('-Dnode_root_dir=' + nodeDir)
if (process.platform === 'aix' || process.platform === 'os390' || process.platform === 'os400') {
  argv.push('-Dnode_exp_file=' + nodeExpFile)
  if (process.platform === 'os390' && zoslibIncDir) {
    argv.push('-Dzoslib_include_dir=' + zoslibIncDir)
  }
}
argv.push('-Dnode_gyp_dir=' + nodeGypDir)

// Do this to keep Cygwin environments happy, else the unescaped '\' gets eaten up,
// resulting in bad paths, Ex c:parentFolderfolderanotherFolder instead of c:\parentFolder\folder\anotherFolder
if (win) {
  nodeLibFile = nodeLibFile.replace(/\\/g, '\\\\')
}
argv.push('-Dnode_lib_file=' + nodeLibFile)
argv.push('-Dmodule_root_dir=' + process.cwd())
argv.push('-Dnode_engine=' +
  (gyp.opts.node_engine || process.jsEngine || 'v8'))
```

You need to override the default settings described in [`node-gyp/addon.gypi`](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/blob/ee46f9d2b56eb238ce5d8199077ce5c98bdbd64c/addon.gypi) and [`node/common.gypi`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/01b7ac60512fe6948dea108a03f06a951bdc02fa/common.gypi)’s `cflags` (C & C++), `cflags_cc` (C++), `ldflags` (Linux), `msvs_settings` (Windows), and `xcode_settings` (OS X). All of them.

In your case, you only set the `cflags`. So, other default settings were left not overridden and thus in effect.

Specifically, you’d want to override the default settings about:

- **the C++ standard to conform**,

  - `cflags_cc`
  - `msvs_settings.VCCLCompilerTool.AdditionalOptions`
  - `xcode_settings.CLANG_CXX_LANGUAGE_STANDARD`
- **floating point arithmetics**,

  - `msvs_settings.VCCLCompilerTool.FloatingPointModel`
- **exceptions**,

  - `cflags_cc`
  - `msvs_settings.VCCLCompilerTool.ExceptionHandling`
  - `xcode_settings.GCC_ENABLE_CPP_EXCEPTIONS`
  - `xcode_settings.GCC_ENABLE_CPP_RTTI`
- **optimization**,
- **the warning level**,
- et cetera.

If you don’t, unintented default settings might be applied.

---

#### Why it defaults to this

Because the Node.js executable is built with the settings and `node-gyp` adopted the settings for the default settings for unknown reasons.

From [the `nodejs/node-gyp` issue #26 — “*Overriding default flags*”](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/26):

> **edhemphill**: Does anyone know why `-fno-rtti` was used as a default? Any particular reason?
>
> **TooTallNate**: **@edhemphill** `node-gyp` uses the same configuration as when `node` itself it built, so the answer is because `node` itself doesn’t need rtti.